# Unable to send context variable to template in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

In my Django view, when I try to assign a variable to my context variable it doesn't work. I basically get data from a request, perform a search based on the request, and assign that search result to my context. Here is my view.py :
**EDIT2**

```
def home(request):
    GET = request.GET
    utilisateur = ""
    context = {}
    if GET.has_key('name'):
        me = UserProfile.objects.filter(facebookId=GET[u'name'])
        utilisateur = me[0].facebookId
        print utilisateur
        context.update({"nom":str(utilisateur)})
        print context.get("nom")    
        return render_to_response('home.html',context)
    else:
        print "Request doenst have a Name variable"
        return render_to_response("home.html",context,
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

now even when I replace the `var` variable with a number, i still cant send it to the template through the context but I can still see its value from the console (notice the `print var` lines)

Am I doing anything wrong here?
**EDIT **

My home.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
<title>Welcome</title>
<script type="text/javascript"    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
var username = "";
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));

  // Init the SDK upon load
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '302210766529054', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//'+window.location.hostname+'/channel', // Path to your Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
        FB.api('/me', function(me){
          if (me.username) {
            document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;
            username = me.username;
            document.getElementById('picture').innerHTML = "<img src = 'https://graph.facebook.com/"+me.username+"/picture'>";
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open('GET','?name='+me.username, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
          }
        })
        document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
        document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
      }
    });

    // respond to clicks on the login and logout links
    document.getElementById('auth-loginlink').addEventListener('click', function(){
      FB.login();
    });
    document.getElementById('auth-logoutlink').addEventListener('click', function(){
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open('GET','?name='+username+'&logout=True', true);
      xmlhttp.send();
      FB.logout();
    }); 
  } 

  }
  );
</script>

<h1>Skèmpi:Rediscover your heritage</h1>
  <div id="auth-status">
    <div id="auth-loggedout">
      <a href="#" id="auth-loginlink">Login</a>
    </div>
    <div id="auth-loggedin" style="display:none">
    <div id="picture"></div>
      Hi, <span id="auth-displayname"></span>  
    (<a href="#" id="auth-logoutlink">logout</a>)
   {{ nom }}


  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 3**

```
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[21/May/2012 01:10:35] "GET /skempi/home HTTP/1.1" 301 0
Request doesn't have a Name variable
[21/May/2012 01:10:35] "GET /skempi/home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3179
dontshare
[21/May/2012 01:10:35] "GET /skempi/home/?name=dontshare HTTP/1.1" 200 3188
```

Comment: Also, ``context`` dictionary is not being sent to template, just the ``{"username": var}``.

Comment: I edited now, still same thing anyway. In my home.html I simply have `{{ nom }}` somewhere (the rest is basically JavaScript SDK initialization etc, should I post that too?)

Comment: Try to use simple template with just one line displaying your var. It should be working.

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately. I added my home.html file. Been dealing with this for 24 hours now !

Comment: Not that this could be the issue but are you going into this if condition --> if GET.has_key(u'myval'): ? You are not setting var in the except loop. Hence var = "" whenever it goes into the except loop. Can you check this?

Comment: Also, if var=None and context  = {'nom':var} when rendered, it will actually print None. So probably, in the try loop, var = user.name is coming out to be None. Are you sure that, when var is hardcoded it's not showing up? Though it seems highly unlikely.

Comment: I was playing around with it more and i changed it to something a lot simpler but still with no luck. Please check EDIT 2 in my original post

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems there could be a number of things going on here.

Have you verified that `settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS` is set correctly and that the `home.html` template is actually being rendered? To verify this, does the SDK boilerplate appear when you try to load the page in a web browser?

I assume you are hitting the correct URL -- `http://127.0.0.1:8000/?name=Mohamed`. Is that correct?

And lastly, does the `print` statement return anything -- which is to say, do you get a response from the `UserProfile` query?

Having verified all of those things, there is some confusion between the context variable names you are using. In `views.py`, you set the context variable `temp`, but in the template `home.html` you try to output the context variable `nom`. This is how I might implement the view:

```
def home(request):
    context = {}
    if 'name' in request.GET:
        me = UserProfile.objects.filter(facebookId=request.GET[u'name'])
        context['nom'] = str(me[0].facebookId)
        print context['nom'] # if you really want see what's been stored 
    else:
        print "Request doesn't have a Name variable"

    return render_to_response("home.html", context,
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Then the rendered page should display the Facebook ID that is returned, wherever you have place the `{{ nom }}`.

Comment: It didn't work, i think it's because of the URL thing you mentioned. Check the original post again (EDIT 3) to see what I get in the console when I tried your code (and same thing with my code actually). I think it may say a lot. Maybe i'm not implementing the AJAX properly?

Comment: When I access the page by manually adding `?name=Mohamed` to URL, everything works as desired. However, when I refresh the page, it doesn't work.

Comment: Yep, the `?name=Mohamed` is the GET parameters portion of the URL that we are accessing in lines 3 and 4 of the view I posted. When you refresh, that is still part of the URL, correct?

Comment: Yeah it's still there when I refresh. how can I make it work without adding the ?name=Mohamed manually??